# Java Streams -> Extract value at a particular index from List<List<String>>

Tags: java, csv, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading a CSV file with Java 8 streams and what is the best way to get the value of a particular column in CSV file 
For eg.

```
firstName,lastName,age,
tom,abraham,18,
liz,abraham,15,
tonny,paul,25
```

I want to extract the second column, so result set would be `abraham;paul`
How can this be done by Java 8 lambda and Streams?

Comment: `data.stream().map(row -> row.get(1)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Could you send me the code for it.
I have something like this
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(csvFilePathName).toURI()))) {
                    List<List<String>> values = lines.map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(";"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    values.forEach(this::print);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: So I have List<List<String>> values, and now from this values I want to get only second index value of inner array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

The CSV file could be read as any other text file, no parser is needed and the [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) with [`File::readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) is sufficient:

```
Set<String> names = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.csv")) // Read all lines of file
                         .stream()                            // Stream them
                         .skip(1)                             // Omit the column names (if any)
                         .map(s -> s.split(";")[1])           // Split by ; and get the 2nd column
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());        // Collect Strings to Set
```

I didn't read the label well. If you already have parsed `List<List<String>>`, the simplest way to achieve the very same result is:

```
Set<String> names = parsedList.stream()
                              .map(row -> row.get(1))       // Get the second column
                              .collect(Collectors.toSet())  // collect to Set<String>
```

Note the following:

- There is not needed the `distinct()` method since collecting to `Set` assures the distinct elements by definition. If you insist on collecting to `List<String>`, replace the last line with:

  ```
   ....
   .distinct()
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

  This way is valid for both of my suggested solutions.
- An exception might appear at the following lines in case of irregular CSV pattern or escaped `;` characters:

  - `map(s -> s.split(";")[1])`
  - `map(list -> list.get(1))`

  Then you need to use a parser.

Comment: thanks Nikolas. 
One more question, how can I see the intermediate result i.e output of skip(1), I meant is there some logging possible in between.

Comment: @tinksabraham: Logging? Do you mean to write to log (SLF4J) or into a console? There is a method `Stream::peek` which behaves the same like `Stream::forEach` but doesn't termintate the stream but returns it as is.

Comment: Stream::peek is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I disagree with *"no parser is needed"*, since CSV data may contain embedded separators, requiring quoted text handling. To get that working correctly, a 3rd-party library, that has been fully tested, is far better than writing your own, and infinitely better than the potential corrupted data that a `split(";")` can produce.

Comment: @Andreas: "The CSV file" - I aimed my answer to the sample CSV file. I am aware the `s.split(";")[1]` might throw the exception and the escaped values won't work. However, this is not the OP's issue yet.

Comment: @Nikolas 
If I have List<List<String>>, how would I be able to extract a particular index value which is unique of inner array??

Comment: @Nikolas True. OPs question starts with *(paraphrased)* "I have CSV data already parsed into `List<List<String>>`", and question is about how to process that data. By not starting there, but instead starting with a (bad) example of CSV-parsing, your answer is unnecessarily muddling the waters.

Comment: @tinksabraham To get unique answers only, use solution [I posted 40 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028484/java-streams-extract-value-at-a-particular-index-from-listliststring/52028659?noredirect=1#comment91007364_52028484) (`data.stream().map(row -> row.get(1)).collect(Collectors.toList())`), but using either `toSet()` or `distinct()` as explained in this answer.

Comment: @Andreas: That's fine. I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Or collect to a `SortedSet`: `stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));`

Comment: @Nikolas They can be lifesaving :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("my.csv")).stream()
        .skip(1)
        .map(s -> s.split(";")[1])
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is the simplest way, but I would prefer to use regular expression and the Matcher for this case.

Comment: What is the point of `replace(";","")` when all semi-colons have already been eliminated by `split(";")`?

Comment: Also, question title says that input is a `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: I am confused, he wants to read values from CSV, and extract only second column values, why he is talking about List<List<String>>?

Comment: Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(csvFilePathName).toURI()))) {
                    List<List<String>> values = lines.map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(";"))).collect(Collectors.toList()

And now I want to extract second column of inner array. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @tinksabraham define "extract". what resulting data type are you hoping for? List<String>, Set<String>, or just a semicolon-joined String perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map stream.

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("file path")).map(row -> row.split(";")).map(row -> row[1]).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

//first map: transform string to Array.
//Second map: choose first index array.
//distinct: remove duplicates elements.
```